# Arduino , Android , Bluetooth Communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, ipc, processing

Hey Guys i have problem ;  i can send data from Phone  to arduino  but i cant send data from arduino to android via Bluetooth on procesing it doesnt work for me . i dont get any Error while compiling  but I cant see anything on phone screen .. i used for blueToothSerial.print(XXX); for arduino side .. and used text(readMessage , width,heigth); for processing side in order to see as a text  Please check it out . Where is my fault ? . What am I missing ? Thanks in Advance

**ARDUINO CODE**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Stepper.h>
#define RxD 6 // This is the pin that the Bluetooth (BT_TX) will transmit to the Arduino (RxD)
#define TxD 7 // This is the pin that the Bluetooth (BT_RX) will receive from the Arduino (TxD)
#define DEBUG_ENABLED 1
#define RELAY 4

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD, TxD);  
int led = 9 ;
int in1Pin = 10;
int in2Pin = 12;
int in3Pin = 11;
int in4Pin = 13;
data = 100;
Stepper motor(512, in1Pin, in2Pin, in3Pin, in4Pin);  
/*----------------------SETUP----------------------------*/
void setup() { 



Serial.begin(9600);//low Serial communication via USB cable to computer (if required)
pinMode(RxD, INPUT); // Setup the Arduino to receive INPUT from the bluetooth shield on Digital Pin 6
pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT); // Setup the Arduino to send data (OUTPUT) to the bluetooth shield on Digital Pin 7
pinMode(13, OUTPUT); // Use onboard LED if required.
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
 motor.setSpeed(30);
 pinMode(RELAY,OUTPUT);
setupBlueToothConnection(); //Used to initialise the Bluetooth shield


} 


/*----------------------LOOP----------------------------*/
void loop() { 
digitalWrite(13, LOW); //Turn off the onboard Arduino LED
char recvChar;
while (1) {
if (blueToothSerial.available()) {//check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();
Serial.print(recvChar); // Print the character received to the Serial Monitor (if required)

//If the character received = 'r' , then change the RGB led to display a RED colour
if (recvChar=='r') {
    motor.step(300);
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);


delay(500);

}

//If the character received = 'g' , then change the RGB led to display a GREEN colour
if (recvChar=='g') {
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  motor.step(-300);


}

//If the character received = 'b' , then change the RGB led to display a BLUE colour
if (recvChar=='b') {

digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
 digitalWrite(RELAY,HIGH);
}

//If the character received = 'x' , then turn RGB led OFF
if (recvChar=='x') {
digitalWrite(led,LOW);
 digitalWrite(RELAY,LOW);
}
}

//You can use the following code to deal with any information coming from the Computer (serial monitor)
if (Serial.available()) {
recvChar = Serial.read();

//This will send value obtained (recvChar) to the phone. The value will be displayed on the phone.
blueToothSerial.print(recvChar);
blueToothSerial.print("burak:");
blueToothSerial.print(data); // data which is defined begin of sketch

}
}
} 



//The following code is necessary to setup the bluetooth shield ------copy and paste----------------
void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
blueToothSerial.begin(9600);// BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=HC-05\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
delay(2000); // This delay is required.
blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
delay(2000); // This delay is required.
blueToothSerial.flush();
}
```

PROCESSING CODE

```
/* BluetoothApp1: Written by ScottC on 25 March 2013 using 
 Processing version 2.0b8
 Tested on a Samsung Galaxy SII, with Android version 2.3.4
 Android ADK - API 10 SDK platform
 Apwidgets version: r44 */

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import apwidgets.*;
public BluetoothSocket scSocket;


//Used for the GUI**************************************
APWidgetContainer widgetContainer; 
APButton redButton, greenButton, blueButton, offButton,yeniButton;
String buttonText="";
int buttonWidth=0;
int buttonHeight=0;
int n=4; //number of buttons
int gap=10; //gap between buttons

boolean foundDevice=false; //When true, the screen turns green.
boolean BTisConnected=false; //When true, the screen turns purple.
String serverName = "ArduinoBasicsServer";

// Message types used by the Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
String readMessage="";

//Used to send bytes to the Arduino
SendReceiveBytes sendReceiveBT=null;

//Get the default Bluetooth adapter
BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

/*The startActivityForResult() within setup() launches an 
 Activity which is used to request the user to turn Bluetooth on. 
 The following onActivityResult() method is called when this 
 Activity exits. */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 if (requestCode==0) {
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 ToastMaster("Bluetooth simdi acildi");
 } 
 else {
 ToastMaster("Programi kullanabilmek icin Bluetoot acmalisiniz!!!");
 }
 }
}


/* Create a BroadcastReceiver that will later be used to 
 receive the names of Bluetooth devices in range. */
BroadcastReceiver myDiscoverer = new myOwnBroadcastReceiver();


/* Create a BroadcastReceiver that will later be used to
 identify if the Bluetooth device is connected */
BroadcastReceiver checkIsConnected = new myOwnBroadcastReceiver();



// The Handler that gets information back from the Socket
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
 switch (msg.what) {
 case MESSAGE_WRITE:
 //Do something when writing
 break;
 case MESSAGE_READ:
 //Get the bytes from the msg.obj
 byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
 // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
 readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
 break;
 }
 }
};



void setup() {
 orientation(LANDSCAPE);

 //Setup GUI********************************
 buttonWidth=((width/n)-(n*gap));
 buttonHeight=(height/2);
 widgetContainer = new APWidgetContainer(this); //create new container for widgets
 yeniButton = new APButton(700,600,(buttonWidth/2),(buttonHeight/2),"Yeni buton");
  redButton =new APButton(0,0 ,400,400, "PERDE YUKARI"); //Create a RED button
// redButton =new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-4)+(gap*1)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "RED"); //Create a RED button
 greenButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-3)+(gap*2)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "GREEN"); //Create a GREEN button
 blueButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-2)+(gap*3)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "BLUE"); //Create a BLUE button
 offButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-1)+(gap*4)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "OFF"); //Create a OFF button
 widgetContainer.addWidget(redButton); //place red button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(greenButton); //place green button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(blueButton);//place blue button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(offButton);//place off button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(yeniButton);
 background(0); //Start with a black background


 /*IF Bluetooth is NOT enabled, then ask user permission to enable it */
 if (!bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
 Intent requestBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
 startActivityForResult(requestBluetooth, 0);
 }

 /*If Bluetooth is now enabled, then register a broadcastReceiver to report any
 discovered Bluetooth devices, and then start discovering */
 if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
 registerReceiver(myDiscoverer, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
 registerReceiver(checkIsConnected, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));

 //Start bluetooth discovery if it is not doing so already
 if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {
 bluetooth.startDiscovery();
 }
 }
}


void draw() {
 //Display a green screen if a device has been found,
 //Display a purple screen when a connection is made to the device
 if (foundDevice) {
 if (BTisConnected) {
 background(170, 50, 255); // purple screen
 }
 else {
 background(10, 255, 10); // green screen
 }
 }


 //Change the text based on the button being pressed.
 text(buttonText, 10, buttonHeight+(buttonHeight/2));

 //Display anything received from Arduino
 text(readMessage, 10, buttonHeight+(buttonHeight/2)+30);
}



/* This BroadcastReceiver will display discovered Bluetooth devices */
public class myOwnBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 ConnectToBluetooth connectBT;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 String action=intent.getAction();
 ToastMaster("Eylem:" + action);

 //Notification that BluetoothDevice is FOUND
 if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
 //Display the name of the discovered device
 String discoveredDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);
 ToastMaster("Bulunan Cihaz: " + discoveredDeviceName);

 //Display more information about the discovered device
 BluetoothDevice discoveredDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
 ToastMaster("getAddress() = " + discoveredDevice.getAddress());
 ToastMaster("getName() = " + discoveredDevice.getName());

 int bondyState=discoveredDevice.getBondState();
 ToastMaster("getBondState() = " + bondyState);

 String mybondState;
 switch(bondyState) {
 case 10: 
 mybondState="BOND_NONE";
 break;
 case 11: 
 mybondState="BOND_BONDING";
 break;
 case 12: 
 mybondState="BOND_BONDED";
 break;
 default: 
 mybondState="INVALID BOND STATE";
 break;
 }
 ToastMaster("getBondState() = " + mybondState);

 //Change foundDevice to true which will make the screen turn green
 foundDevice=true;

 //Connect to the discovered bluetooth device (SeeedBTSlave)
 if (discoveredDeviceName.equals("HC-05")) {
 ToastMaster("BAGLANIYOR!!");
 unregisterReceiver(myDiscoverer);
 connectBT = new ConnectToBluetooth(discoveredDevice);
 //Connect to the the device in a new thread
 new Thread(connectBT).start();
 }
 }

 //Notification if bluetooth device is connected
 if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
 ToastMaster("CIHAZINIZ BAGLANDI");
 int counter=0;
 while (scSocket==null) {
 //do nothing
 }
 ToastMaster("scSocket" + scSocket);
 BTisConnected=true; //turn screen purple 
 if (scSocket!=null) {
 sendReceiveBT = new SendReceiveBytes(scSocket);
 new Thread(sendReceiveBT).start();
 String red = "r";
 byte[] myByte = stringToBytesUTFCustom(red);
 sendReceiveBT.write(myByte);
 }
 }
 }
}

public static byte[] stringToBytesUTFCustom(String str) {
 char[] buffer = str.toCharArray();
 byte[] b = new byte[buffer.length << 1];
 for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
 int bpos = i << 1;
 b[bpos] = (byte) ((buffer[i]&0xFF00)>>8);
 b[bpos + 1] = (byte) (buffer[i]&0x00FF);
 }
 return b;
}

public class ConnectToBluetooth implements Runnable {
 private BluetoothDevice btShield;
 private BluetoothSocket mySocket = null;
 private UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

 public ConnectToBluetooth(BluetoothDevice bluetoothShield) {
 btShield = bluetoothShield;
 try {
 mySocket = btShield.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
 }
 catch(IOException createSocketException) {
 //Problem with creating a socket
 Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error with Socket");
 }
 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
 /* Cancel discovery on Bluetooth Adapter to prevent slow connection */
 bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();

 try {
 /*Connect to the bluetoothShield through the Socket. This will block
 until it succeeds or throws an IOException */
 mySocket.connect();
 scSocket=mySocket;
 } 
 catch (IOException connectException) {
 Log.e("ConnectToBluetooth", "Error with Socket Connection");
 try {
 mySocket.close(); //try to close the socket
 }
 catch(IOException closeException) {
 }
 return;
 }
 }

 // Will allow you to get the socket from this class
 public BluetoothSocket getSocket() {
 return mySocket;
 }

 /* Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
 public void cancel() {
 try {
 mySocket.close();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
 }
 }
}



private class SendReceiveBytes implements Runnable {
 private BluetoothSocket btSocket;
 private InputStream btInputStream = null;
 ;
 private OutputStream btOutputStream = null;
 String TAG = "SendReceiveBytes";

 public SendReceiveBytes(BluetoothSocket socket) {
 btSocket = socket;
 try {
 btInputStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
 btOutputStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
 } 
 catch (IOException streamError) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Error when getting input or output Stream");
 }
 }

 public void run() {
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
 int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

 // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
 while (true) {
 try {
 // Read from the InputStream
 bytes = btInputStream.read(buffer);
 // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
 mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
 .sendToTarget();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
 Log.e(TAG, "Error reading from btInputStream");
 break;
 }
 }
 }

 /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
 public void write(byte[] bytes) {
 try {
 btOutputStream.write(bytes);
 } 
 catch (IOException e) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Error when writing to btOutputStream");
 }
 }

 /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
 public void cancel() {
 try {
 btSocket.close();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) { 
 Log.e(TAG, "Error when closing the btSocket");
 }
 }
}



/* My ToastMaster function to display a messageBox on the screen */
void ToastMaster(String textToDisplay) {
 Toast myMessage = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
 textToDisplay, 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 myMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
 myMessage.show();
}




//onClickWidget is called when a widget is clicked/touched
void onClickWidget(APWidget widget) {
 String sendLetter = "";

 //Disable the previous Background colour changers
 foundDevice=false;
 BTisConnected=false;

 if (widget == redButton) { //if the red button was clicked
 buttonText="RED";
 background(255, 0, 0);
 sendLetter = "r";
 }
 else if (widget == greenButton) { //if the green button was clicked
 buttonText="GREEN";
 background(0, 255, 0);
 sendLetter = "g";
 }
 else if (widget == blueButton) { //if the blue button was clicked
 buttonText="BLUE";
 background(0, 0, 255);
 sendLetter = "b";
 }
 else if (widget == offButton) { //if the off button was clicked
 buttonText="OFF";
 background(0);
 sendLetter = "x";
 }
  else if (widget == yeniButton) { //if the off button was clicked
 buttonText="yeni buton";
 background(100,100,100);
 sendLetter = "y";
 }

 byte[] myByte = stringToBytesUTFCustom(sendLetter);
 sendReceiveBT.write(myByte);
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem of communication. Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678968/arduino-android-bluetooth-communication